# Why does ltablex skip a number in captions?

Tags: tables, floats, captions, tabularx

The below example presents two tables with an `tabularx` environment (taken from package `ltablex`) and a caption. After each `tabularx`-table, the table counter skips one, as if both the `caption` and the `tabularx` environment increase it, while the latter shouldn't.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption 1.} % "Table 1"
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|}
empty table
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption 2.} % "Table 3"
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|}
empty table
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

My reputation doesn't allow me to upload a picture, but the captions are Table 1 and Table 3 respectively.

Comment: Consider using the `tabu` package.

Comment: Note that the document would work as you have it if you used the standard `tabularx` package version of `tabularx` instead of the `ltablex` version.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I realized that, but I needed `ltablex` for a different table and cannot use them side-by-side (right?).

Comment: @roelandvanbeek ltablex includes tabularx (and then changes it) so no you can not use the original in that case., you could use my own merger of tabularx and longtable instead: `ltxtable` package. but Herbert's answer is the usage intended by ltablex I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ltablex` behaves like a `longtable`, the reason why you should use the `\caption` as a tabular line:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|}
\caption{Caption 1.}\\ % "Table 1"
empty table
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|}
\caption{Caption 2.}\\ % "Table 2"
empty table
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```