# Table numbering skips 1

Tags: tables, numbering, tabularx

I am working with the classicthesis template and have inserted tables. However, numbering of tables skips. In this case, the first table shown below has the number "Table 2.2" and the second table shown below then comes with "Table 2.4". There is nothing more in between the code of the two tables than shown below. Any idea where this may come from?

To me it seems that the error stems from a package called `ltablex`, which I wanted to use for a table earlier in the text that runs across two pages. If I do not load the `ltablex` environment but only `tabularx` , the numbering works well. Any suggestion how I can keep using `ltablex`but get numbering right?

Many thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{ltablex,caption,setspace, booktabs, enumitem}
\begin{document}
        \begin{table}[!h]
        \centering
        \begin{spacing}{.9}
            \footnotesize
            \caption{Caption 1}\label{Table 1}
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{0.55\linewidth} p{0.45\linewidth} }
                \toprule
                \textbf{Col 1}  & \textbf{Col 2} \\
                \midrule
                Text & Text \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{spacing}
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \centering
        \begin{spacing}{.9}
            \footnotesize
            \caption{Caption 2}\label{Table 2}
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{0.55\linewidth} p{0.45\linewidth} }
                \toprule
                \textbf{Col 1}  & \textbf{Col 2} \\
                \midrule
                Text & Text \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{spacing}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A full MWE is not your entire document (which we REALLY don't want), it just has to be executable and demonstrate the problem.  Also, the process of removing all extraneous materials often solves the problem.

Comment: Please keep in mind that `tabularx` at least needs one `X` type column. This is not the case in your document.

Comment: Pls see updated question / MWE. ltablex seems to cause the problem, but not sure how to solve it given that I would like to use ltablex in another place.

Comment: Thanks, Leandriis. As I am a LaTex novice, can you help me understand: would I then go to a tabular environment if I do not use at least one x column?

Comment: Try to use `xltabular` instead of `ltablex`. It works fine in your case as well at long table with `X` columns.

Comment: @Christian: You only need `ltablex` if you have at least one table in your document that is longer than a page and needs flexible width `X` type columns. If that's the case, I'd also suggest to switch to `xltabular` instead. If you have a table that is longer than a page but does not need `X` type columns, go for `longtable`. Regarding the tables in your example: As long as they don't exceed one page, you can simply use `tabular` instead of `tabularx`.

Comment: [Why does ltablex skip a number in captions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110031/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these comments! Am just experimenting with xltabular, which already has solved some of the issues I was facing :)

Comment: Since the culprit for the table number skipping seems to be the combination of `ltablex` with captions that are not placed correctly (according to `ltablex`), I have voted to close your question as a duplicate to [Why does ltablex skip a number in captions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110029/why-does-ltablex-skip-a-number-in-captions)