# Wrong numbering of tables

Tags: tables, numbering, tabularx

I have an issue with the numbering of my tables : [image]

As you can see, there are several numbers missing, like 2.5 or 4.3, but I have no idea why this is.

For the editor, I have to work with [dgruyter.sty](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1s1tv0eg9ejluqe/dgruyter.sty?dl=0) stylesheet.
Here is part of my code :

```
\documentclass[openany,ngerman]{book}
\usepackage[main=french,italian, spanish, portuguese, latin, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{microtype}
\baretabulars

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}
Text: 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|p{19mm}|p{19mm}|p{14mm}|X|}
    \hline
    A & B & C & D & E \\ 
    \hline
    A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 & E1 \\
    \hline 
\end{tabularx} 
 \end{small}
    \captionof{table}{XXX}

\begin{small}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|p{19mm}|p{19mm}|p{14mm}|X|}
    \hline
    F & G & H & I & J  \\ 
    \hline
    F1 & G1 & H1 & I1 & J1  \\
    \hline 
\end{tabularx} 
\end{small}
    \captionof{table}{YYY}
    \end{document}
```

In my document, the output is following : [image]

It seems like this happens between `tabular` and `tabularx` tables, but in the above case it also happens between 2 tables where I used `tabularx`. I don't know what I can do to make it right.

I really would appreciate your help in this question.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this could be related to ltablex.

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110031/134144

Comment: Use [xltabular](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) for multiple page tables. It will handle the caption numbering correctly.

Comment: @Sveinung Thank you, xltabular works perfectly!